# Angular 4 raw string from ActivatedRoute params

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have been searching everywhere I could not find an answer on this. I'm passing a string on the url example. "localhost:4200/home/ABCD%2BrAD4Og%3D%3D" when I subscribe to the param or use snapshot I get something like "ABCD+rAD4Og=="
How do I get what was exactly passed? Thank you

Comment: you can use you can use UrlSerializer to avoid url encoding or use navigateByUrl instead of navigate, it should work

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer. If you want to get the raw param that was passed all you have to do is use "encodeURIComponent(uri)"

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-example',
template: `<h1>raw URI example</h1>`,
styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) {}
rawUri: string = null;
ngOnInit() {
this.router.params.subscribe(param => {
// the "id" part inside param[''] could be anything you defined in your route config file.
this.rawUri = encodeURIComponent(param['id']);
console.log('raw url param ', this.rawUri);
    }
  }

}
```